# Aligning tikzpicture to Center of Box?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I need to align the arrows in the following LaTeX so that they are moved up to the midpoint of the boxes. Meaning halfway up the box instead of aligned at the bottom like they are now. Here is my current code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}

\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}

\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}
\renewcommand*{\DefaultHeightofChoiceMenu}{22ex}
\renewcommand*{\DefaultWidthofChoiceMenu}{10ex}


\begin{document}

\begin{Form}

    \ChoiceMenu[print,combo,default=Box 1,name=box1,color=0.862745 0.0784314 0.235294]{}{Item 1,Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5}
    \quad
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-1,2) -- (0,2); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \ChoiceMenu[print,combo,default=Box 2,name=box2, color=0.196078 0.803922 0.196078]{}{Item 1,Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5}
    \quad
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-1,2) -- (0,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \ChoiceMenu[print,combo,default=Box 3,name=box3, color=0.196078 0.803922 0.196078]{}{Item 1,Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5}
    \quad
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-1,2) -- (0,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \ChoiceMenu[print,combo,default=Box 4,name=box4, color=0.862745 0.0784314 0.235294]{}{Item 1,Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5}
    \quad
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-1,2) -- (0,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \ChoiceMenu[print,combo,default=Box 5,name=box5, color=0.862745 0.0784314 0.235294]{}{Item 1,Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5}

\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just `raise` every `arrow`.

[image]

Once finished, tikzpictures are aligned on its baseline. In this case, tikzpicture dimensions are 1cm long and almost nothing high. Coordinates `(-1,2)` and `(0,2)` only have sense inside the tikzpicture, but once finished only picture size matters. Therefore vertical position `2` means nothing in this case. But you can use a `\raisebox` to move its `baseline` where you need it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}

\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}

\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}
\renewcommand*{\DefaultHeightofChoiceMenu}{22ex}
\renewcommand*{\DefaultWidthofChoiceMenu}{10ex}

\newcommand{\myarrow}{\raisebox{11ex}{\tikz \draw[->] (0,0)--++(1,0);}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}

    \ChoiceMenu[print,combo,default=Box 1,name=box1,color=0.862745 0.0784314 0.235294]{}{Item 1,Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5}
    \quad\myarrow\quad
        \ChoiceMenu[print,combo,default=Box 2,name=box2, color=0.196078 0.803922 0.196078]{}{Item 1,Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5}
    \quad\myarrow\quad
    \ChoiceMenu[print,combo,default=Box 3,name=box3, color=0.196078 0.803922 0.196078]{}{Item 1,Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5}
    \quad\myarrow\quad
    \ChoiceMenu[print,combo,default=Box 4,name=box4, color=0.862745 0.0784314 0.235294]{}{Item 1,Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5}
    \quad\myarrow\quad
    \ChoiceMenu[print,combo,default=Box 5,name=box5, color=0.862745 0.0784314 0.235294]{}{Item 1,Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```